# configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables - Buildozer kivy to android debuging

Tags: android, python, gcc, kivy, buildozer

ENTERING MY PROBLEM (they can skip it)
Hello, I am trying to compile apk application, but I always have many problems due to lack of libraries and applications that my system does not bring and that are not mentioned in the buildozer and kivy requirements. I am stuck in this error after installing a lot of libraries to solve the previous ones. If you have the definitive guide of requirements to work with buildozer and kivy please add it as a complement to this answer. If you think it is better to format the system and start again to install only what is necessary, I am willing, as long as the information you give me is different from what is available in the official pages.

PROBLEM
I have: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, Python 2.7.15rc1, Kivy v1.11.0.dev0, Buildozer 0.35
Libraries imported in the .py: kivy, uuid, sqlite3

File buildozer.spec

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Turnos

# (str) Package name
package.name =turnosapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python2, android, kivy, sqlite3, uuid

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 18b

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activites = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to stable
#p4a.branch = stable

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Terminal error:

```
lagerta@lagerta-OptiPlex-790:~/Kivy/Dandole/TurnosApp$ buildozer android debug
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration toke...
........................hide text.............................
[INFO]:    sqlite3 said it is already built, skipping
[INFO]:    Building python2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running cp /home/lagerta/Kivy/Dandole/...(and 231 more)
[INFO]:    -> running cp /home/lagerta/Kivy/Dandole/...(and 229 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/lagerta/Kivy/Dandole/TurnosApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python2-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a/python2
[INFO]:    -> running cp /home/lagerta/Kivy/Dandole/...(and 121 more)
[INFO]:    -> running gcc -dumpmachine
[INFO]:    -> running configure --host=arm-eabi --bu...(and 229 more)
           working: checking for arm-eException in thread background thread for pid 6910:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/lagerta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2170, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/lagerta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1929, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/lagerta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 672, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
ErrorReturnCode_77: 

  RAN: ./configure --host=arm-eabi --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/lagerta/Kivy/Dandole/TurnosApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python2-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a/python2/python-install --enable-shared --disable-toolbox-glue --disable-framework

  STDOUT:
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... 32-bit
checking MACHDEP... linux4
checking EXTRAPLATDIR... 
checking machine type as reported by uname -m... x86_64
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for arm-eabi-gcc... /usr/bin/ccache arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer -D__ANDROID_API__=19 -isystem /home/lagerta/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r18b/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -isysroot /home/lagerta/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r18b/sysroot -I/home/lagerta/Kivy/Dandole/TurnosApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/turnosapp/include/python2.7
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/lagerta/Kivy/Dandole/TurnosApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python2-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a/python2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details


  STDERR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/lagerta/Kivy/Dandole/TurnosApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 978, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/lagerta/Kivy/Dandole/TurnosApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 975, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/lagerta/Kivy/Dandole/TurnosApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 512, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/home/lagerta/Kivy/Dandole/TurnosApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 149, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/lagerta/Kivy/Dandole/TurnosApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 193, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx)
  File "pythonforandroid/build.py", line 573, in build_recipes
  File "/home/lagerta/Kivy/Dandole/TurnosApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/recipes/python2/__init__.py", line 44, in build_arch
    self.do_python_build(arch)
  File "/home/lagerta/Kivy/Dandole/TurnosApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/recipes/python2/__init__.py", line 122, in do_python_build
    _env=env)
  File "pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 175, in shprint
  File "/home/lagerta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 720, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/lagerta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 651, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/lagerta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 672, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_77: 

  RAN: ./configure --host=arm-eabi --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/lagerta/Kivy/Dandole/TurnosApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python2-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a/python2/python-install --enable-shared --disable-toolbox-glue --disable-framework

  STDOUT:
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... 32-bit
checking MACHDEP... linux4
checking EXTRAPLATDIR... 
checking machine type as reported by uname -m... x86_64
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for arm-eabi-gcc... /usr/bin/ccache arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer -D__ANDROID_API__=19 -isystem /home/lagerta/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r18b/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -isysroot /home/lagerta/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r18b/sysroot -I/home/lagerta/Kivy/Dandole/TurnosApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/turnosapp/include/python2.7
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/lagerta/Kivy/Dandole/TurnosApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python2-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a/python2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=turnosapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python2,android,kivy,sqlite3,uuid --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/lagerta/Kivy/Dandole/TurnosApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build"
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: have you found a solution?